# Tem problema de escrever múltiplas perguntas na mesma pergunta?

Tags: debate, perguntas

```
- Alguém sabe um jeito melhor de implementar tal método?, ou 
- Como posso instalar manualmente ?, ou
- Existe outro pacote que me ajuda a resolver o problema?
```

Mesmo que seja *pertinente*, posso dar opções/múltiplas perguntas para as pessoas querendo me ajudar com a minha pergunta? É irrelevante isso ou tenho que escrever só uma frase para deixar a pergunta mais limpa de qualquer maneira?

Comment: Eu estava respondendo, porque deletou? kkkkkk

Comment: porque eu nunca sei quando a pergunta é estupida. sendo de programação ou não.

Comment: Faça a pergunta independente do que acha. Sempre vai aparecer alguém tentando responder. Caso haja algum problema sempre você vai receber um feedback ou pelo fechamento da pergunta caso o problema seja grave ou por comentários no caso de detalhes. Se ainda ficar vago para você você pode abrir um tópico aqui no META sob a tag [tag:pergunta-específica] pedindo esclarecimento.

Comment: Tem que tomar cuidado, detalhamento da dúvida com "subperguntas" é uma coisa, postar sobre mais de um problema já não funciona. Tem inclusive um fechamento específico para isso, que é "Muito Ampla".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Resumo

A dúvida deve ser objetiva. Você precisa colocar no conteúdo da sua pergunta contextualizado com sua dúvida. **Eu** diria que não tem problemas, desde que você faça dentro do escopo do site.

### Minha experiência pessoal

Eu vou contar um pouco da minha experiência no site.

Costumo fazer algumas "subperguntas" nas perguntas que faço por aqui.

Como por exemplo:

- [Para que serve o atributo loading="lazy" em imagens e iframes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/489936/para-que-serve-o-atributo-loading-lazy-em-imagens-e-iframes)
- [Quais as diferenças entre o Decoradores e Atributos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/487648/quais-as-diferen%c3%a7as-entre-o-decoradores-e-atributos)
- [Como funcionam os atributos do PHP 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/487642/como-funcionam-os-atributos-do-php-8)

Ao meu ver, dividir a pergunta em alguns pequenos "tópicos" pode até mesmo facilitar a pessoa que vai respondê-la.

Porém eu sempre tento não colocar como "subpergunta" algo que já tenha sido respondido no site, ou algo que possa deixar a pergunta muito ampla, ou baseada em opiniões. Além disso, as perguntas precisam estar relacionadas ao assunto que foi perguntado.

Se for o caso, até sugiro que separe as perguntas em duas ou três posts diferentes, mas raramente precisei de algo assim.

#### Cuidado ao adicionar "subperguntas" depois de uma resposta ter sido dada

Como regra pessoal, eu procuro sempre definir as "subperguntas" que vão ser feitas quando estou escrevendo o post. Quando preciso adicionar mais uma "subpergunta", sempre verifico se alguma resposta já não foi dada, pois, se eu acrescentar algo após ter sido dada uma resposta, posso deixar a resposta atual desatualizada.

Comment: Eu gosto da suas suas pergunta, inclusive estou ganhando dinheiro com uma delas, sobre um protocolo em especial(abriu um novo campo para mim).

Comment: kkkkkkk sério? Me ensina a fórmula =)

Comment: Eu só li e me abriu um mundo novo. O melhor que era um momento que eu estava precisando.